# Assigning mesh to bones

Tags: rigging, bones, vertex-groups

I am new to Blender and having some issues following tutorials along where the mesh is assigned to bones. I have created a mesh and an armature. Bones are working as expected. At this point I am supposed to be able to parent the mesh to the armature by selecting the mesh, shift selecting the armature and then Ctrl-P, Parent with empty groups. Then I should select portions of the mesh and assign to vertex groups. One problem is I am unsure of the steps required to do this. Once I get the mesh portion selected (in Edit mode) I cannot find where the vertex groups are to assign. I may be in the wrong mode but the tutorials get a little vague (to me) at this point. Also, when I eventually can find the vertex groups it seems they are not all there. When I Parent with empty groups, should it create vertex groups for each bone?

I need a simple straight forward tutorial on this process.

Thank you

Comment: Yes in the Object Data panel > Vertex Groups, you should see the list of vertex groups the parentage has created, then you select the vertices you want in the mesh, select the vertex group you want in the list, and press on the Assign button

Comment: Is there a particular mode I should be in? I seem to only be able to select the mesh when in Edit mode, but then the vertex groups are not available. I'm so confused as the tutorials make it seem so simple. And as I said before, it appears that not all the vertex groups are being created when I parent. Unless I am misunderstanding this altogether.

Comment: maybe share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Hopefully this works, first time trying this. https://pasteall.org/blend/af8f805ea59848379c635d360a8335ff

Answer (score 1):

You must have made a mistake at some point. First click on the *Vertex Groups* dropdown menu and *Delete All Groups*:

[image]

Also delete the *Armature* modifier in the *Modifiers* panel. Select the armature and in *Edit* mode, select the controller and target bones, go in the *Bone* panel and disable their *Deform* option.

Now parent the robot object again with the *With Empty Groups* option (not *Automatic Weight* which is made for organic things). Select the robot object, switch to *Edit* mode, select the left foot for example, go into the *Vertex Groups* list, select *Foot.L*, press *Assign*, and so on for the other parts:

[image]

Comment: Success!!! Thank you so much. Now, any idea what I did wrong so I can avoid it in the future? Also, the Foot.R vertex group was not created and I had to manually create it. Is this a bug in Parenting with Empty Groups? Where does the Armature modifier come from? Is that created when the parenting is performed? Thank you again for your help.

Comment: mmh Foot.R should be here, when you parent With Empty Groups it will create as many Vertex Groups as you have bones (as long as their Deform option is enabled) and the vertex group will share the exact same name as the bones. It's a way of parenting that is ideal for machines and robots as it doesn't assign any vertex to any group, it let you do it.

Comment: The modifier will automatically appear as soon as you parent with one of the Armature Deform options (so With Empty Groups or With Automatic Weight). You didn't have to delete the previous modifier as it had no armature selected but it was just in order to make it clean.

Comment: Well, almost success. I see now that the vertex group for Foot.R, the one I had to create, is not working. But I'm further along than before!

Comment: make sure that you have not disabled its Deform option by mistake. Actually you don't really have to disable the Deform option for these bones when parenting WIth Empty Groups but it was just a way to explain how it works

Comment: Are there any known bugs with 2.93.4? This is so frustrating. After going into animation and discovering the issue with Foot.R, now it seems none of the mesh is connected to the  bones anymore. WTH did I do? I've had meshes just disappear also. I think I will drop back to an earlier version if possible.

Comment: please share the file you're working on so that I find where the problem is

Comment: I deleted everything as before and tried again. Now all vertex groups have been created and the mesh is now moving as expected in Pose mode. Note to self! Make sure all vertex groups exist before continuing. Oh, I also upgraded to 2.93.5 so I don't know if that had anything to do with it.

Comment: @Toroso don't forget to click the check-mark to the left at the top of the answer to accept.  moonboots donates lots of personnal time to answer questions.  the points earned help his reputation.